# Examples of different type of entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I try to answer following question. I would like to find a general approach for part b, since I think any entire function with $n $ roots is either polynomial of degree $n$ or is a product of polynomial with another entire function with no roots.

> Give an example of an entire function that is not a polynomial hand has
>
> a) no root;
>
> b) exactly $n$ roots;
>
> c) infinitely many roots.

For part a) I think $e^z$ works.

Part b) I think $f(z)=e^zP(z)$, where $P(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. However,I would like to know if there is any entire function not constructed by any polynomial.

For part c) I think $g(z)=\sin(z)$, which $z=n\pi$, where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Take any non-polynomial, entire function $f(z)$ that has no zeroes.  Then, $g(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n(f(z)-f(z_k))$ is entire, has $n$ zeroes, and is not a polynomial.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers are fine. As for your separate question: let $f$ be entire with only $n$ roots $z_i, i=1\ldots n$. If $\alpha_i$ is the order of the root $z_i$, then $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{\prod_{i=1}^n (z-z_i)^{\alpha_i}}$$
is an entire function with no roots. Therefore $f$ is the product of a polynomial and an entire function with no roots.